# Corona SDK android keyboard and native textFields

Tags: java, android, coronasdk

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android using Corona SDK and have problems with managing native textFields in Android.

I'm trying to achieve the following effects:

1. tapping on textfield will animate its sliding with keyboard so it will be always on top of it while moving up.
2. Tapping on back button will dismiss the keyboard and slide textfield back with it

My problems are:

1. To know the height of the keyboard in order to know where to stop moving the textfield.
2. To catch back button tap in order to eliminate the textfield

What I am doing:

1. I've looked over the Internet to find out how to check keyboard height on Android. All solutions assume we have Activities.
2. We have registered `onKey` listener to catch back press in corona code, but it is not fired if keyboard shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I made this Draw & Guess Online game and I used Native TextFields as well.  What I did is just set my device resolution to lets say 600x1024. Then I just tested on a few different devices, and just eyeballed where the keyboard was located.  I'm afraid this is what your going to have to do.  Just use a for loop to make around 10 small rectangles and print the pixel values next to each of them.  Then take your test devices, and see where the keyboard lyes on each device.  Then just animate them up.

There is no easy way to do it in Corona unfortunately.  Also people could have custom keyboards which would make your life even more difficult.  All I can recommend is to over estimate and release.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Actually I'm already doing this as temporary workaround but my goal now is to do it correctly. I'm still looking for a solution.